# How to import active directory data into an array and export that into a single CSV file?

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, active-directory

How do I export active directory data (email addresses and telephone numbers) into a single CSV file?

I have exported Active Directory data into an array and export the array into a CSV file but the CSV file is showing as empty

```
# Change directory to where the CSV files are located
cd "C:\Users\srobins\OneDrive - Ruralco Holdings Limited\Desktop"

# Declare an array and assign the list of users to this
$users = Get-Content users.csv

# Create an array for the active directory data to be stored
$displayname = @()

# Loop through the list of users
foreach ($user in $users) {

# Get the active directory data and store in a tempory variable
$displaynamedetails = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter { DisplayName -eq $name }| Select name,samAccountName,OfficePhone

# Append the active direcotry data into the array
$displayname += $displaynamedetails

}

#export the array containing the list of active directory data into the new CSV
$displayname | Export-Csv "C:\SamAccountName.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I am expecting the CSV file 'SamAccountName' to be created and the list of Active Directory data is stored inside.

The CSV file is being created however, it is empty.

Comment: Try changing `$name` to `$user`.

Comment: Thanks Drew, 

Can't believe I missed something so stupid! 

Unfortunately, this did not help the CSV Export is still empty

Answer (score 0):

Parameter LDAPFilter in **Get-ADUser** does not use the syntax you have there.

You need to use -LDAPFilter "(displayName=$user)" or keep existing syntax and change parameter to -Filter {DisplayName -eq $user}

Comment: Unfortunately, both of these do not work.          

Changing the query to `-LDAPFilter "(displayName=$user)"` comes back with **Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: '-LDAPFilter (displayName=Heather Cosgriff)**'.           

Changing the query to `-Filter {DisplayName -eq $user}` comes back with **Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized**.         

Thanks

Comment: Based on error message I think you put some additional quotes or double quotes into your script. For example Cannot find an object with identity: '-LDAPFilter (displayName=Heather Cosgriff)' seems like result of calling "-LDAPFilter (displayName=$user)" instead of -LDAPFilter "(displayName=$user)". I tested the solution before posting so perhaps you will need to post the whole line starting with $displaynamedetails = for review if you cannot find the issue yourself

Answer (score 0):

So I see that you are using a csv. Which means, `Get-content` is the wrong choice of cmdlet. You have to use `Import-csv`. Csv also means you have a header on that file.

[image]

So when you do this

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
   $user
}
```

You will get returned data in this format through each iteration of the `foreach loop`.

[image]

What you need is this.

```
 # Change directory to where the CSV files are located
cd "C:\Users\srobins\OneDrive - Ruralco Holdings Limited\Desktop"

# Declare an array and assign the list of users to this
$users = Import-Csv users.csv

# Create an array for the active directory data to be stored
$displayname = @()

# Loop through the list of users
foreach ($user in $users.Name) #$users.Name has to reflect the header you have. In my case it was name.
{

# Get the active directory data and store in a tempory variable
$displaynamedetails = Get-ADUser -filter "DisplayName -eq '$user'" | Select name,samAccountName,OfficePhone #mind the '' around $user

# Append the active direcotry data into the array
$displayname += $displaynamedetails

}

#export the array containing the list of active directory data into the new CSV
$displayname | Export-Csv "C:\SamAccountName.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

EDIT2----------------------------------------

I would strongly suggest adding a header, otherwise, why use a csv?
If that is not the case, you have to do some not so ideal text manipulation.

```
# Change directory to where the CSV files are located
cd "C:\Users\srobins\OneDrive - Ruralco Holdings Limited\Desktop"

# Declare an array and assign the list of users to this
$FileContent = Get-Content users.csv
$Users = $FileContent | ForEach-Object {($_.Split(",")[0]).trim()}
#[0] is the position of the name part in each line when it is split into parts at the comma. Eg: John Doe,32,blah
#In my case it was the 1st part. Change this according to ur data

# Create an array for the active directory data to be stored
$displayname = @()

# Loop through the list of users
foreach ($user in $users) #$users.Name has to reflect the header you have. In my case it was name.
{

# Get the active directory data and store in a tempory variable
$displaynamedetails = Get-ADUser -filter "DisplayName -eq '$user'" | Select name,samAccountName,OfficePhone #mind the '' around $user

# Append the active direcotry data into the array
$displayname += $displaynamedetails

}

#export the array containing the list of active directory data into the new CSV
$displayname | Export-Csv "C:\SamAccountName.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Perhaps it would be helpful to see a sample data of the csv.

Comment: @RohinSidarth  

I am using CSV to work with PowerShell however, there are no headers thus if I was to `Import-CSV` the header would be my first user's name.  

However, when I change my AD Query to `$displaynamedetails = Get-ADUser -filter "DisplayName -eq '$user'" | Select name,samAccountName,OfficePhone` I am getting the following error **Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'DisplayName -eq 'Robyn O'Brien'' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '26'**  

Thanks

Comment: BTW with these edits, I can't get the line break to work even following the guide. 

To get the linebreak I leave 2 spaces at the end of the line correct?

Comment: @RohinSidarth

I am unexperienced with this editor and unable to link images, let alone create a linebreak.

I ahve followed your Edit2 and it mostly works - I found my main errors were users with aprostrophe's in their names but fixed this up. 

Now my script is running without errors but still exporting a blank CSV.

Could this be due to the script hitting a user that does not exist and exiting?
If so how would I add a check to see if the user exists and if they don't or that space is blank to skip and keep on going with the rest?